# How to make the output of the code come out as "Wage minus Tax

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm creating a simple monthly wage calculator by "minusing" the tax from the wage. Every person has different tax depending on how much they earn monthly, (at this stage.)

However, this code outputs the tax and not the wage minus tax.

I've already tried several things for eg; making new varaibles which (try too) minus the tax from wage, although neither of these things worked.

(I'm a begginner c++ programmer, so any help would be appreciated) Please take this into account

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float mWage = 0;
    cout << endl << "Now please type your exact monthly wage: ";
    cin >> mWage;
    cout << endl;

    char taxtable[7][100]{" $0 - $19,050 = (1)","$19,501 - $77,400 = (2)","$77,401 - $165,000 = (3)","$165,001 - $315,000 = (4)","$315,001 - $400,000 = (5)","$400,001 - $600,000 = (6)","$600,001 or more = (7)"};

    for (int taxpr = 0; taxpr < 7; taxpr++)
        cout << taxtable[taxpr] << " " << endl;

    cout << endl << "Now please type the number corrospondiong to your monthly wage: ";
    int taxValue = 0;
    cin >> taxValue;
    cout << endl;

    double one = 10;
    double two = 12;
    double three = 22;
    double four = 24;
    double five = 32;
    double six = 35;
    double seven = 37;

    double one1 = (one / 100) * mWage;
    double one2 = (two / 100) * mWage;
    double one3 = (three / 100) * mWage;
    double one4 = (four / 100) * mWage;
    double one5 = (five / 100) * mWage;
    double one6 = (six / 100) * mWage;
    double one7 = (seven / 100) * mWage;

    switch (taxValue) {
        case 1:
            cout << "This is your wage minus tax: $" << one1 << endl;
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "This is your wage minus tax: $" << one2 << endl;
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "This is your wage minus tax: $" << one3 << endl;
            break;

        case 4:
            cout << "This is your wage minus tax: $" << one4 << endl;
            break;

        case 5:
            cout << "This is your wage minus tax: $" << one5 << endl;
            break;

        case 6:
            cout << "This is your wage minus tax: $" << one6 << endl;
            break;

        case 7:
            cout << "This is your wage minus tax: $" << one7 << endl;
            break;


        default: 
            cout << "Incorrect Value!";

    } 
}
```

I expect the output to be "wage - tax," but the actual output is just the tax of the wage.

Comment: Where are you subtracting the tax from the wage?

Comment: `oneN` is wage multiplied by appropriate tax factor. It is what you output. What do you expect? You could apply basic percent-math and calculate not the tax but the remainder... It is very unclear what your problem is.

Comment: I think you would not get into this kind of trouble if you learned about arrays, or at least about naming variables according to their semantic meaning. If a variable contains the tax percentage, then call it e.g. `tax_percentage`, instead of `one` and `tax_amount` instead of `one1`.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to output it to show wage minus tax? Like show some code?

Answer (score 0):

When you're calculating `one1` and so on, you're not subtracting the tax from the original wage. Try something like
`double one1 = mWage - (one / 100) * mWage;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it still outputs the same thing